# SQL - Merge two rows with similar values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table called areas in a PostgreSQL server:

```
| id | name    | code    | shape   | created  | cars
=======================================================
| 1  | name 1  | code 1  | shape 1 | created1 | cars 1
| 2  | name 1  | code 1  | shape 2 | created2 | NULL
| 3  | name 2  | code 2  | shape 3 | created3 | cars 2
| 4  | name 2  | code 2  | shape 4 | created4 | NULL
.
.
.
```

So basically it's nearly duplicate entries that have the same name and code, but different id, shape and created timestamp. What I want is to merge those duplicate rows, but overwrite the "shape" and "created" fields with the values of the newest entry. So eventually the above table would look like the following :

```
| id | name    | code    | shape   | created  | cars
======================================================
| 1  | name 1  | code 1  | shape 2 | created2 | cars 1
| 3  | name 2  | code 2  | shape 4 | created4 | cars 2
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to achieve this? There is the limitation that the duplicate, newer, entries already exist in the table, so it's not possible to just update the previous entries by inserting the new ones.
I want to store afterwards the results in the same table.

Comment: You dont need to overwrite (unless you want to preserve the ids?) . Just retain the records you want to keep, [ = delete the records you dont want to keep]

Comment: I want to overwrite so I keep the ids actually. So it's partial overwrite. I want to keep the id from the "older" entry and the shape and created from the "newer" entry.

Comment: Please note that contrary to your statement the IDs of the duplicates *are different*. Which is expected by e.g. using identity column. So you want to introduce a new colums IS_DUPLICATE_OF filled in the older dups pointing to the newer dup row.

Comment: Create a view ```WHERE cars IS NOT NULL``` combined with ```LAG``` or ```LEAD``` window function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

- update the lower ids using the later ids
- delete the later ids that are no longer needed.

---

```
UPDATE ztable dst
SET shape = src.shape
        , created = src.created
FROM ztable src
WHERE src.name = dst.name
AND src.code = dst.code
AND src.id > dst.id
        ;

DELETE FROM ztable del
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM ztable x
        WHERE x.name = del.name
        AND x.code = del.code
        AND x.id < del.id
        );
```

---

If there are more than two *duplicates* you'll have a problem: which of the upper ones should you use for the update?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses arrays to implement a "first" aggregation function:

```
select id, name, code, max(created),
       (array_agg(shape order by created desc))[1] as shape,
       max(cars) as cars
from t
group by id, name, code;
```

Comment: That works on retrieving the results I expect. I am wondering how I can store them afterwards in the same table, instead of just retrieving them. I guess probably a combination with update statement.

Comment: @kon176 . . . That would require deleting rows as well.  I would suggest you run this query, store the results in a temporary table.  Then truncate the original table and re-insert the fixed rows.